# Sybase DEFAULT timestamp value

Tags: sql, sybase

I have a sybase table with update_datetime column and this column has to be updated whenever insert/update happens. I have created table as below

```
 CREATE TABLE items 
 (
    name VARCHAR(90),
    update_datetime DATETIME DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    price NUMERIC(7,2)
 );
```

after insert, I can see current date time is getting updated

```
 INSERT INTO items(name, price) VALUES ('Apple', 1.29);
```

But after update, I don't see this column getting updated, still the old value updated during insert is there.

```
UPDATE items SET price = price - 0.2 WHERE name = 'Apple';
```

I am not sure why? Please help to identify the cause

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is Sybase ASE 15.x/16.x ...

A column's DEFAULT only applies on INSERT operations.

To have the `update_datetime` column updated with each UPDATE statement you'll need to use a trigger or redefine `update_datetime` as a computed column; for the latter you typically define a function call that references another column in the table that you expect will always be modified with an UPDATE statement, eg:

```
CREATE TABLE items 
(name             VARCHAR(90)
,price            NUMERIC(7,2)
,ts               timestamp
,update_datetime  compute dateadd(ss,0*ts,getdate()) materialized
)
```

**NOTE:** the computed column definition must appear after the column(s) referenced in the computed column; in this case `update_datetime` must be listed after `ts`

The `timestamp` datatype is a special Sybase ASE datatype; when used to define a column ASE will automatically update said column each time any part of the row is modified/updated:

- upside: we don't need to know in advance what columns might be updated (to place in the computed column definition)
- downside: we add a 8-byte `timestamp` column to the table

Since the `ts` column will always be modified on an UPDATE statement, and because the `timestamp` value is stored as a 8-byte binary, we can negate its value with `*0`; the resulting `0` seconds (`ss`) is then added to `getdate()` to derive a new value for the `update_datetime` column; net result: `update_datetime` is updated with the datetime of each UPDATE statement applied against this row.